# updating fields matching condition under not nice path

Tags: jq

I need very often update conditionally some fields in subtree to which leads ugly path. I kinda can solve it, but it's very ugly solution, I'd like to know if there is smth better.

**Sample input**:

```
{
  "very": {
    "un-fortunate": {
      "p-a-t-h": {
        "first": {
          "veryDeepSubTree": {},
          "someValue": 1
        },
        "second": {
          "veryDeepSubTree": {},
          "someValue": 2
        },
        "third": {
          "veryDeepSubTree": {},
          "someValue": 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**desired output**: say that I would like to add 10 to *someValue*. Suppose that I cannot use recursive descent, for example I want to update only odd *someValue*.

I can write solution like this:

```
jq '.very|=(.["un-fortunate"]|=(.["p-a-t-h"] |=(  . as $root| reduce keys[] as $k ({}; . + {($k): ($root|.[$k]|.someValue|=(.+10))})      )))'
```

but it's hard to read and write (matching brackets)...

explained motivation, based on my (*mis*?)understanding:

- iiuc I need to bracket every non-trivial right operand of |= , especially if there are more of them, otherwise it does not compile
- I cannot express longer path than just one field at a time, if path is sufficiently ugly
- there isn't other way(maybe except foreach, which I cannot understand) to update all items of object, than using reduce to copy all into new updating value, and update each part in update clause of reduce command

questions:

- is there some better way of expressing unfortunate path from tree root?
- can I express it somehow easier than via using this reduce over keys, and putting field update logic into accumulator part of reduce command?
- if you are writing commands into shell, how do you do it so that you can easily edit it + it's readable?

Comment: Why can't you use recursive descent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [array value iterator `[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D) in combination with the [(arithmetic)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arithmeticupdate-assignment:+=,-=,*=,/=,%=,//=) [update-assignment operator `|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=).

To update all `someValue`s:

```
.very."un-fortunate"."p-a-t-h"[].someValue |= . + 10
```

or

```
.very."un-fortunate"."p-a-t-h"[].someValue += 10
```

To update only `someValue`s which are odd, filter through [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) and don't forget to parenthesize the LHS):

```
(.very."un-fortunate"."p-a-t-h"[].someValue | select(. % 2 != 0)) += 10
```

Output:

```json
{
  "very": {
    "un-fortunate": {
      "p-a-t-h": {
        "first": {
          "veryDeepSubTree": {},
          "someValue": 11
        },
        "second": {
          "veryDeepSubTree": {},
          "someValue": 2
        },
        "third": {
          "veryDeepSubTree": {},
          "someValue": 13
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But even recursive descent would work, you just have to make sure to only select the correct values:

```
(.. | objects | .someValue | values | select(. % 2 != 0)) += 10
```

or

```
(.. | .someValue? | values | select(. % 2 != 0)) += 10
```

Output is identical to above.

Comment: `|= . + 10` can further be shortened to `+= 10`.

Comment: I knew this can be very simplified :) Coming from imperative programming this often feels like magic, I didn't realized I can combine it like this. Your answer helped me A LOT in general, not just with this specific problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinMucha yes, it takes some getting used to, but once you do, jq is really really great (and the syntax becomes _mostly_ intuitive; not always though :))

Comment: @knittl jq is great indeed, it enables us to do stuff easily, which would be otherwise pretty dire task. I walked a long way understanding it, but it happens more often than I'd think, that my observed relative position to the end of route drastically changes as new horizons appears behind hill :) But it's you guys, who made all this learning possible. Thanks for creating great community most tools don't have. It's OT sure(sorry about that), but I think you deserve this explicit 'thank you'.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach using `walk` is worth knowing about:

```
walk(if try (.someValue % 2 != 0) catch false then .somevalue += 10 else . end)
```

Or with fewer keystrokes:

```
walk(if (.someValue% 2 != 0)? // null then .somevalue += 10 else . end)
```

Or a bit more targeted:

```
(try (.[][][][].someValue) | select(. % 2 != 0)) += 10
```